# Spark Streaming - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Error

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter4j

I am trying to access the streaming tweets from Spark Streaming.

This is the software configuration.

> Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

scala -version

> Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

spark-submit --version

> Spark version 1.6.0

Following is the code.

```
object PrintTweets
{
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

  // Configure Twitter credentials using twitter.txt
  setupTwitter()

  // Set up a Spark streaming context named "PrintTweets" that runs locally using
  // all CPU cores and one-second batches of data
  val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "PrintTweets", Seconds(1))

  // Get rid of log spam (should be called after the context is set up)
  setupLogging()

  // Create a DStream from Twitter using our streaming context
  val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)


  // Now extract the text of each status update into RDD's using map()
  val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())

  // Print out the first ten
  statuses.print()

  // Kick it all off
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
 }
}
```

Utilities.scala

```
object Utilities {
/** Makes sure only ERROR messages get logged to avoid log spam. */
def setupLogging() = {
  import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}   
  val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
  rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)   
}

/** Configures Twitter service credentials using twiter.txt in the   main workspace directory */
def setupTwitter() = {
  import scala.io.Source

  for (line <- Source.fromFile("./data/twitter.txt").getLines) {
   val fields = line.split(" ")
   if (fields.length == 2) {
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + fields(0), fields(1))
   }
 }
```

}

}

Issues:

Since it needs the twitter4j library, i have added
twitter4j-core-4.0.4, twitter4j-stream-4.0.4 in eclipse build path as external jars.

Then i ran the program, it didnt throw any error. But the tweets not appearing in console. It were empty.

So i see some forums and downgraded twitter4j to 3.0.3. Also in Eclipse i chosen Scala 2.10 Library container in Build Path window.

After that i got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError run-time error.

```
16/05/14 11:46:01 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V
at    org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:72)
at   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help me to resolve this. Initially i have installed spark by built using Scala 2.11. Is that the problem. Do i need uninstall everything and re-install Scala 2.10, then Spark pre-compiled package.

Or apart from Scala 2.11, do i need to have Scala 2.10 in my system?

Comment: You have answered your own question. Since everything your getting is in scala 2.11, why you cose Scala 2.10 n Eclipse?  Could you change it to Scala 2.11, and try again?

Comment: Hey thanks everyone. I am able to solve it after looking into Spark UI by seeing the process graph. I am running the program inside VM and the problem was due to `local[*]` setting. After i changed it to `local[2]`, i am able to see the tweets. I think `local[*]` is not able to acquire enough threads for processing the input streaming tweets.

Comment: Frankly, I do not see how this had resolved the problem. IMHO, the problem has nothing to do with the amount of resources assigned to the job. But good for you anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

The above exception seems to be caused by the incompatibility of `spark version 1.6.0` and `twitter4j 3.0.3 version`.

`twitter4j.TwitterStream` which is being passed in the `onStart` method of `org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver`, has method addListener which takes instance of `twitter4j.StreamListener`.

`twitter4j 3.0.3 version` has no method `twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(StreamListener)`, instead it has few other `addListener` methods, which take the subclass of `StreamListener`.

`twitter4j 4.0.4 version` has the desired method, so that's why no error comes with this library. So changing to `twitter4j 3.0.3 version` will not solve the problem.

Problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case.
I had spark java project. 
I cleaned pom file and start adding in order. First resolved spark related errors, then spark launcher, next on ward based on bigger library.
Note I was using cdh6.2.0 environment